# Automatic voice listener used in mic and speaker in background services

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which have the feature of automatic voice listener if app also in background service, if user use mic at any point, need to record the voice and to save in Internal storage

I have tried record mic when app is running it's working, but closing app its not working or using mic I have sent voice message, it also not saving in Internal storage

(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#java),

I have referred to this example for record mic

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AudioManager audioManager;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
private static String mFileName=null;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

//Requesting permission
private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName+= "/audiorecordtest.mp3";
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions,REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

    startRecording();

    audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(MainActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);

    try{
        if (null != mRecorder) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.reset();
            mRecorder.release();

            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }catch(RuntimeException stopException){

    }

   }

   private void startRecording(){

    mRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Workingg Da", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Working");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"IllegalState Exception");
    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"prepare()failed");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed Recording", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
            permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
    }
    if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

}

private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Error: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Warning: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
};
```

I expect the output, when user using mic or speaker need to record, even the app is closed and store it in internal storage, any listener method kindly post here, it will help me to complete.

Thanks Friends

Comment: Please include relevant code to show what you have tried already.

Comment: Application that records everything even when it's not running? I really hope that's impossible to do.

Comment: @dharms Updated code

Comment: @James Z  not everything, henuser using mic or speaker, it should record becoz in many apps they have included the audio record option without make any phone calls they can easily communicate using (i.e, Whatsapp audio calling, audio record and sending) if mic has been used need to record that audios and store